# How to add p value column in a data frame comparing row wise?

Tags: r, dplyr

For the example dataset iris, I would like to compute a table that gives me the p values for a t-test comparing the species Sentosa and Versicolor to Virginia (i.e. Virginia would be the reference group/control)

Currently, I've processed the average values for columns (sepal length, sepal width, petal length, petal width) and am trying to do a t-test grouped by species against control.

as an example output would have these columns:

c=Sepal Width p value, Sepal length p value, Petal length p value, Petal width p value

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Edit 1:
Here is what I wrote applied to iris (which doesn't exactly fit). I basically cleaned up my data to only include certain independent variables, which is why I have so the %>%.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(species) %>%
  addcol = function(iris)%>%
    Sepal.length.p.value = mutate(iris, function(t.test(vars(3), ~./[species == 'Sentosa'])))
```

and basically I did that for each of the independat variables.

Comment: Well have you tried anything? If yes, please share us what you actually tried!

Comment: I have but nothing I've tried works. I also have tried it with the data set I'm working with which is a bit different but here it is with the iris dataset put into it - I've added to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)

pivot_longer(iris,-Species) %>% group_by(name) 

# A tibble: 600 x 3
# Groups:   name [4]
   Species name         value
   <fct>   <chr>        <dbl>
 1 setosa  Sepal.Length   5.1
 2 setosa  Sepal.Width    3.5
 3 setosa  Petal.Length   1.4
 4 setosa  Petal.Width    0.2
 5 setosa  Sepal.Length   4.9
 6 setosa  Sepal.Width    3
```

At this step, we have converted into long and group them according to the variable. It is a matter of applying a pairwise t.test within each group, and filtering out those you don't need. We can use broom for this:

```
res = pivot_longer(iris,-Species) %>% group_by(name) %>% 
do(tidy(pairwise.t.test(.$value,.$Species,pool.sd =FALSE))) %>% 
filter(group1=="virginica" | group2=="virginica")

    # A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   name [4]
  name         group1    group2      p.value
  <chr>        <chr>     <chr>         <dbl>
1 Petal.Length virginica setosa     2.78e-49
2 Petal.Length virginica versicolor 4.90e-22
3 Petal.Width  virginica setosa     7.31e-48
4 Petal.Width  virginica versicolor 2.11e-25
5 Sepal.Length virginica setosa     1.19e-24
6 Sepal.Length virginica versicolor 1.87e- 7
7 Sepal.Width  virginica setosa     9.14e- 9
8 Sepal.Width  virginica versicolor 1.82e- 3
```

Note that I set pool.sd =FALSE in pairwise.t.test so that it would be similar to a t.test, but ideally, if you have many groups, and their variances are similar, it pays to use a pooled SD.

You can put this in wide format again:

```
pivot_wider(res,values_from=p.value,names_from=name)
    # A tibble: 2 x 6
  group1    group2     Petal.Length Petal.Width Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width
  <chr>     <chr>             <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1 virginica setosa         2.78e-49    7.31e-48     1.19e-24 0.00000000914
2 virginica versicolor     4.90e-22    2.11e-25     1.87e- 7 0.00182
```

Comment: While I upvoted @StupidWolf answer as IMHO the most elegant code solution.  Some comments about methodology for @Shailaja-Chadha you don't have multiple independent variables you have multiple **dependent** variables with a 3 level independent variable and should probably start with `summary(manova(cbind(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) ~ Species, data = iris))` and the associated `aov`s.  I would **NOT** use `t.test` since that doesn't allow you to adjust for the multiple comparisons. `pairwise.t.test` at least applies the Holm correction by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution: Cycle through the variable names in `iris` using `purrr::map_dfc()` and within that `map_dfc()` you cycle through the treatment groups (versicolor and setosa) with `purrr::map_dfr()`. That way the results of the inner cycle are combined rowwise and the results of the outer cycle are combined columnwise.

```
var_names <- names(iris)
var_names <- var_names[-length(var_names)] # Last variable is the group/Species variable, we don't want to include that.
treat_group <- c(versicolor = "versicolor", setosa = "setosa") # Using a named vector here will help map_dfr() to give useful names to the rows, otherwise it would just be 1 and 2.

library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map_dfc(var_names, function(x) {
  map_dfr(treat_group, function(y) {
    res <-
      tibble(t.test(iris[x][iris$Species == "virginica",],
                    iris[x][iris$Species == y,])$p.value)
    names(res) <- x
    res
  }, .id = "species")
}) %>%
  select(-matches("[1-3]")) # drop columns with numeric characters in it, to get rid of repeated species columns
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   species    Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <chr>             <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1 versicolor     1.87e- 7 0.00182           4.90e-22    2.11e-25
#> 2 setosa         3.97e-25 0.00000000457     9.27e-50    2.44e-48
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split your data into control and treatment groups and use `dplyr::summarise` within your groups to create a column that gives you the p-value of a t-test.

```
library(dplyr)

control <- iris %>%
  filter(Species == "virginica")

dat <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(Species != "virginica") %>%
  summarise("Sepal Width p value" = t.test(Sepal.Width, control$Sepal.Width)$p.value,
            "Sepal length p value" = t.test(Sepal.Length, control$Sepal.Length)$p.value,
            "Petal length p value" = t.test(Petal.Length, control$Petal.Length)$p.value,
            "Petal width p value" = t.test(Petal.Width, control$Petal.Width)$p.value)
```

With the output being:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  Species    `Sepal Width p value` `Sepal length p value` `Petal length p value` `Petal width p value`
  <fct>                      <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>                 <dbl>
1 setosa             0.00000000457               3.97e-25               9.27e-50              2.44e-48
2 versicolor         0.00182                     1.87e- 7               4.90e-22              2.11e-25
```