# In R, how to write function that runs t-test on list of dataframes

Tags: r, excel, list, dataframe, split

Using `iris` dataset as an example, I want to write a user defined function that

1. run `pairwise t-test` on all 4 columns exempting `Species` columns for each data split
2. export the results as 3 worksheets of a csv file

See below for my attempt:

```
library(tidyr)
library(reshape) # for melting /stacking the data
library(multcomp) # for pairwise test 
library(xlsx) # export excel file with worksheet

options(scipen = 100)

# dataset
iris

data_stats <- function(data){
    # melt the dataframe
     df <- melt(data, id.vars=c('Species'),var='group')
    
# split the dataframe into three list of dataframe
    dfsplit<-split(df,df$column)
    
    #  pairwise t-test
    results <- pairwise.t.test(dfsplit$value, dfsplit$group,p.adjust.method = "BH")
    
    # export each result as a worksheet of an excel file
    write.xlsx(results, file="Results.xlsx", sheetName="versicolor_stats", row.names=FALSE)
    write.xlsx(results, file="Results.xlsx", sheetName="virginica_stats", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
    write.xlsx(results, file="Results.xlsx", sheetName="setosa_stats", append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
    
}
# testing the code on iris data
data_stats(iris)
```

Please comment and share your code. Thanks

Comment: In the loop, you may need `[[` instead of `$` i.e. `df[[column]]` or `df[[group]]` if both are passed as string names

Comment: You probably don't want all the results written to each sheet, I would expect `write.xlsx(results[<<some subsetting logic>>], ...)`

Comment: @Akrun,please share your full code. thanks

Comment: @GregorThomas, kindly share your full code

Comment: Your `dfsplit` is a list.  It needs to be looped with `results_lst <- lapply(dfsplit, \(x) pairwise.t.test(x$value, x$group, p.adjust.method "BH"))`

Comment: @akrun, can you post your full code in "Post Your Answer" so I can run it and subsequently vote as the accepted answer. Also, please include the exporting excel part of the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @nasa313 Neither me nor akrun have "full code" at this point. We're trying to help you along... Typically with homework questions (and other questions too) you learn the most if you mostly do it yourself.

Comment: I am a bit confused by your code.  The `pairwise.t.test` returns a list of output.  You may need to `tidy` it i.e. `library(broom); with(iris, tidy(pairwise.t.test(Sepal.Length, Species)))`

Comment: @akrun, the code is my attempt, I am open to other approach, All I want is to run a` t-test` on 3 subsets  of `iris` dataframe ( 3 unique levels) and export them as tabs of an excel file.

Comment: You could write in a single file, i.e. `iris %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Species) %>% group_by(Species) %>% group_modify(~ .x %>% summarise(out = list(pairwise.t.test(value, name) %>% tidy))) %>% ungroup %>% unnest(out)`

Comment: @GregorThomas,Thanks for your comment. I was wondering how would you attempt running a `t-test` on a `dataset with three unique classes using iris` dataframe as an example (iris has three unique species)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the accepted solution doesn't perform the t-tests that you intend to perform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse` - reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, then use `group_modify` to do the `pairwise.t.test` , `tidy` the output and `unnest` the `list` output

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
ttest_out <- iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_modify(~ .x %>%
     summarise(out = list(pairwise.t.test(value, name) %>% 
       tidy))) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   unnest(out)
```

-output

```
ttest_out
# A tibble: 18 × 4
   Species    group1       group2         p.value
   <fct>      <chr>        <chr>            <dbl>
 1 setosa     Petal.Width  Petal.Length 1.77e- 54
 2 setosa     Sepal.Length Petal.Length 2.77e-132
 3 setosa     Sepal.Length Petal.Width  1.95e-156
 4 setosa     Sepal.Width  Petal.Length 1.61e- 86
 5 setosa     Sepal.Width  Petal.Width  1.13e-123
 6 setosa     Sepal.Width  Sepal.Length 4.88e- 71
 7 versicolor Petal.Width  Petal.Length 5.35e- 90
 8 versicolor Sepal.Length Petal.Length 3.78e- 52
 9 versicolor Sepal.Length Petal.Width  5.02e-125
10 versicolor Sepal.Width  Petal.Length 1.36e- 45
11 versicolor Sepal.Width  Petal.Width  3.46e- 44
12 versicolor Sepal.Width  Sepal.Length 1.25e- 95
13 virginica  Petal.Width  Petal.Length 1.39e- 90
14 virginica  Sepal.Length Petal.Length 6.67e- 22
15 virginica  Sepal.Length Petal.Width  3.47e-110
16 virginica  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length 2.35e- 68
17 virginica  Sepal.Width  Petal.Width  1.87e- 19
18 virginica  Sepal.Width  Sepal.Length 2.47e- 92
```

Comment: thanks, how do I export the results as a csv or excel file? Do I just `write.csv(out.csv)`?

Comment: @nasa313 yes, you can with `write.csv` as `write.csv(ttest_out, "path/to/your/out.csv", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: where is the `ttest_out` dataframe in your code? Your code only has `out` dataframe

Comment: @nasa313 i.e. the output object name if you check my code `ttest_out <- iris %>% ..`  Please refresh the browser in case it is not updated

Comment: Thanks alot, I am going to upvote now.

Comment: @akrun The t-tests above don't make sense: group1 and group2 are meant to be two levels of a categorical variable. Instead you have group1 = Petal.Width and group2 = Petal.Length, etc. What does that even mean?

Comment: @dipetkov I was also confused by the OP's code.  I posted a solution only because of the request to share a code based on his code

Comment: @akrun I realize that your solution is correct programatically: it does literally what the OP asks. And I've learned not to get distracted by what might the output mean if it's the output requested.

Answer (score -1):

*Update*: The statistical part of this question (applying `pairwise.t.test` to the iris dataset) has been [answered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60662491) on SO. And [here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-perform-t-test-for-multiple-variables-in-r-pairwise-group-comparisons/) is another solution.

The accepted solution runs a series of pairwise t-tests and produces a column of p-values (exactly as the question asks) but it's a not very meaningful set of t-tests. You might suspect that from the fact that we see p-values like 2.77e-132 and that group1 and group2 are continuous variables, not the levels of a factor.

The hypotheses that these tests evaluate is whether, for each species separately, sepal is the same as petal and length is the same as width. The pairwise t-test procedure is designed to compare a single continuous variable (say sepal length) across all the levels a factor (say species).

To begin with, let's apply `pairwise.t.test` to the column `Sepal.Length`, so that we can check later on that we get the right p-values.

```r
library("broom")
library("tidyverse")

pairwise.t.test(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Species)
#> 
#>  Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
#> 
#> data:  iris$Sepal.Width and iris$Species 
#> 
#>            setosa  versicolor
#> versicolor < 2e-16 -         
#> virginica  9.1e-10 0.0031    
#> 
#> P value adjustment method: holm
```

If you've ever seen the iris dataset, you know these p-values "make sense": Virginica & Versicolor are more similar to each other than to Setosa.

So now let's apply the tests in a tidy way to the four numeric columns.

```r
t_pvals <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -Species,
    names_to = "Variable",
    values_to = "x"
  ) %>%
  # The trick to performing the right tests is to group the tibble by Variable,
  # not by Species because Species is the grouping variable for the t-tests.
  group_by(
    Variable
  ) %>%
  group_modify(
    ~ tidy(pairwise.t.test(.x$x, .x$Species))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
t_pvals
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    Variable     group1     group2      p.value
#>    <chr>        <chr>      <chr>         <dbl>
#>  1 Petal.Length versicolor setosa     1.05e-68
#>  2 Petal.Length virginica  setosa     1.23e-90
#>  3 Petal.Length virginica  versicolor 1.81e-31
#>  4 Petal.Width  versicolor setosa     2.51e-57
#>  5 Petal.Width  virginica  setosa     2.39e-85
#>  6 Petal.Width  virginica  versicolor 8.82e-37
#>  7 Sepal.Length versicolor setosa     1.75e-15
#>  8 Sepal.Length virginica  setosa     6.64e-32
#>  9 Sepal.Length virginica  versicolor 2.77e- 9
#> 10 Sepal.Width  versicolor setosa     5.50e-17
#> 11 Sepal.Width  virginica  setosa     9.08e-10
#> 12 Sepal.Width  virginica  versicolor 3.15e- 3
```

The p-values for the Sepal.Width comparisons are at the bottom. We got the p-values we expected!

Next we format the p-values so that they are easier on the eyes.

```r
t_pvals <- t_pvals %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      p.value, rstatix::p_format,
      accuracy = 0.05
    )
  )
t_pvals
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    Variable     group1     group2     p.value
#>    <chr>        <chr>      <chr>      <chr>  
#>  1 Petal.Length versicolor setosa     <0.05  
#>  2 Petal.Length virginica  setosa     <0.05  
#>  3 Petal.Length virginica  versicolor <0.05  
#>  4 Petal.Width  versicolor setosa     <0.05  
#>  5 Petal.Width  virginica  setosa     <0.05  
#>  6 Petal.Width  virginica  versicolor <0.05  
#>  7 Sepal.Length versicolor setosa     <0.05  
#>  8 Sepal.Length virginica  setosa     <0.05  
#>  9 Sepal.Length virginica  versicolor <0.05  
#> 10 Sepal.Width  versicolor setosa     <0.05  
#> 11 Sepal.Width  virginica  setosa     <0.05  
#> 12 Sepal.Width  virginica  versicolor <0.05
```

And finally we save the results to a file.

```r
t_pvals %>%
  write_csv("pairwse-t-tests-on-iris-data.csv")
```

Comment: thanks for your attempt. I like the way you commented the code, its easier to understand. One more thing, is it possible to highlight or color the `p.value < 0.05` and export as a csv file

Comment: All the p-values are smaller than 0.05. The largest p-value is 0.0031 in the bottom row.

Comment: I know for `iris`, they are all have p.values less than `< 0.05`, I want to use the code on other datasets (not just `iris`) hence the highlight the `p.value <0.05` and export as `xlsx` or `csv` file. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is R, so probably there are many options for formatting p-values. I like `rstatix::p_format`.

Comment: Anyway, I'll stop editing now. I think the statistics is correct & clear!

Comment: couple of things, p.value returns `<0.0001` instead of the full number like `0.00000001` I think the `<` impedes the rstatix::p_format from highlighting the p.values less than 0.05.  I think `options(scipen = 100)` should help with the suppression of scientific notation

Comment: Sure. Personally I don't like changing the global options. It's better that you post this as another question. Ask "I have a column of p-values and I want them formatted like this".

Comment: I have shared the output of your code in the original post, the `p.value` column is not highlighted

Comment: You can't highlight a csv file. You've imported the csv data in excel. I just wanted to correct the statistics for you and anyone else who might read this question. Ask another question about the highlighting.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. Really appreciate it!

Comment: since you intend on correcting the statistics, we are comparing `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` and not the the '`Species`. The desired output should return `Species` column and `Sepal.....` and `Petal......`  as `Group 1` and `Group 2` and not `Species` as `Group 1` and `Group 2`. kindly refer to the first response `ttest_out`. thanks

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation of `pairwise.t.test` or `t.test` for that matter? Have you seen anyone perform a t-test comparing the measurements of two different features X1 and X2?

Comment: yes , http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-way-anova-test-in-r,  refer to the  `pairwise.t.test(my_data$weight, my_data$group, p.adjust.method = "BH")` part of it, this what i am using

Comment: You may also consider going over to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) the sister website for statistical questions and ask there for feedback about the statistical analysis.